# Why using render-props instead of just passing the component as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Just out of curiosity, what is the difference between this:

```
const Parent = ({Child}) => {
  return <div><Child name="pedro"></Child></div>
}

const Child = ({name}) => {
  return <div>{name}</div>
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Parent Child={Child}></Parent>
  );
}
```

And this:

```
const Parent = ({render}) => {
 return <div>{render("pedro")}</div>
}

const Child = ({name}) => {
  return <div>{name}</div>
 }

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Parent render={name=><Child name={name}></Child>}></Parent>
  );
}
```

Both achieve the same result but for some reason the second way (render props) is waaaay more popular than the fist one and I just can't find any differences or articles talking about it.